# DOCX4J variable prepare cause trouble when open a saved docx

Tags: java, xml, docx4j

I use `docx4j` to replace variable in a model, the replacement and the save works fine but there is a problem when I open the new docx:

> The file [.docx] cannot be opened because there are problems with the contents.

So I made a test with just open and immediately save it with a new name like that:

```
WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = Docx4J.load(new File(sourceFile));
wordMLPackage.save(new java.io.File("result.docx") );
```

And I don't have the problem yet, but it reappears when I call the function `VariablePrepare.prepare()` like this :

```
WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = Docx4J.load(new File(sourceFile));
VariablePrepare.prepare(wordMLPackage);
wordMLPackage.save(new java.io.File("result.docx") );
```

I also try with an empty document but the problem still remain ...
 [sourceFile](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=24907820805945944069)

So, I think it's `VariablePrepare` which is problematic but I don't know how to fix it and I need to use that function.

Comment: You'll need to post somewhere the sourceFile which causes the problem

Comment: It's done, and it's didn't work with all sourceFile I've tried

Comment: Can't help unless you add a link to the sourceFile

Comment: http://www.fast-files.com/getfile.aspx?file=139360 leads into a morass of advertising, and I could not download your file

Answer (score 0):

Answered at your crosspost at https://www.docx4java.org/forums/docx-java-f6/variableprepare-cause-trouble-in-a-new-doc-t2572.html